# In javascript do you have to init a variable?

Tags: javascript

Is it require, good practice or a waste of time to initialize a variable? Take a look at instance in this code, is this correct?

```
var instance = ''
var myArgs = require('optimist').argv,

switch (myArgs._[0]) {
    case 'insult':
        var instance = 'insult'
        console.log(myArgs.n || myArgs.name, 'smells quite badly.');
        break;
    case 'compliment':
        var instance = 'compliment'
        console.log(myArgs.n || myArgs.name, 'is really cool.');
        break;
    default:
        console.log(help);
 }
```

Comment: You are redeclaring the `instance` variable in each case, so the first `var instance = ''` is redundant.

Comment: [Interesting read](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:r4FS_NTjiWoJ:blog.safeshepherd.com/23/how-one-missing-var-ruined-our-launch/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Please don't forget to use `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put `var` twice.
 Javascript is a dynamic language, so you can create a var with first an `int`, then a `string` and then a `function`. You don't have to say `int` before.

In your example :

```
var instance = ''
var myArgs = require('optimist').argv,

switch (myArgs._[0]) {
 case 'insult':
     instance = 'insult'
     console.log(myArgs.n || myArgs.name, 'smells quite badly.');
     break;
 case 'compliment':
     instance = 'compliment'
     console.log(myArgs.n || myArgs.name, 'is really cool.');
     break;
 default:
     console.log(help);

}
```

Of course, if you want to ensure that your var is a `string` use `typeof`. Example:

```
if(typeof instance !== 'string'){
   alert('should be a string')
}
```

Comment: Thanks on the guidance on not doing var twice, this is my first app!

Answer (score 2):

### Assigning

If you try to assign to an uninitialised variable then you will create a global. This is bad, don't do this.

If you have enabled strict mode, then you will throw a reference error. This is bad, don't do this.

### Reading

If you try to read from an uninitialised variable, you will throw a reference error. This is bad, don't do this.

### In short

Always initialise your variables.

Note that JavaScript scope is handled at the *function* level, not the block level and `var` statements are *hoisted*.

It is generally considered good practise to declare your variables only once, and at the top of the function. Remove the `var` from your `instance` except for the one you have at the top of your function.

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages in general, it's often recommended that you initialize variables so they are set to a known state.  This can often help you catch errors.

Having said that, in Javascript, uninitialized variables have the value undefined, which you can check for, so it's doubtful if you will gain much by this -- unless there is a useful default value for that variable.